# How do you rank tf idf values to use

Tags: python, rank, tf-idf, subquery

Say that you have generated a tf idf value for each term in a document

But when it comes to queries of multiple terms for example "hey well done" It'll return multiple tf idf values for each document, for example....

```
{2: [0.00527108433734938, 0.005271084337249398]}
```

How would I rank this or which tf idf value would I use? Appreciate any responses, thank you!

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

Comment: whats this for?

Comment: It's a tfidf vectorizer that doesn't return multiple values for each term in a document